# exclude partitions in select query

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have a table in hive which is partitioned based on country.
I want to exclude 3 specific partition like somalia,iraq.
I do not want to give in where clause (not in 'somalia','iraq').
Do we have option to exclude specific partitions like (we have exclude columns from the select statement)?.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **drop the partitions** that are not needed,

```
hive> alter table <db_name>.<table_name> drop partition 
      (<partition_filed>="somalia"),(<partition_filed>="iraq");
```

**`(or)`**

Create a **view on top of the table** by excluding the partitions that are not needed.

```
hive> create view <db_name>.<view_name> as select * from <db_name>.<table_name> 
        where <partition_filed> not in ("somalia","iraq");

hive> select * from <db_name>.<view_name>;
```